# Finger touch signal detection with microcontroller

Tags: touch

I use darlington transistor for detection of touching. Finger or hand touch to BASE, only make about 0.8-0.9V voltage on the EMITTER side. How can i increase this voltage level to 3V for detecting touch event with a microcontroller? 0.8-0.9V is not adequate for digital inputs.
I've read sth. like TTP223B or AT42QT1012 on this forum. But i'm not sure, isn't there a way with transistors or simpler ways without utilizing an IC? (The method that i search must be robust at different conditions like that wet or dry finger)

[image]

Comment: You could connect that that darlington to another darlington or BJT. SImilar to how Q3 is connected to Q2.

Comment: Sensing the change in capacitance when a finger displaces air might be more reliable.

Comment: sure, capacitive sensing needs special peripheral in uC or external circuit. we try to find simpler way, just using digital input of uC.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this type of touch sensor is that it relies on sufficient capacitive coupling through an unknown path. A battery operated device may be too isolated to get a good response.

However you could get better results by rearranging the transistors to pull down rather than up, as this should make better use of the signal relative to ground. A complementary configuration may work even better because it only has one Base-Emitter voltage drop rather than two. For this you need one NPN and one PNP transistor. You can also increase sensitivity by using a higher value load resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwYeVd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>